# What sort of denomination might believe that those in Heaven work?

Tags: heaven, comparative-christianity, non-denominational

At a recent "celebration of life" for my brother-in-law's step-dad (which I did not attend, this is secondhand knowledge), BIL's step-brother made reference to the dad now getting to work forever in Heaven. "Work" as in, doing a 9-5 job like you do on Earth.

I don't believe the step-brother is formally a part of any denomination.

What might be the theology behind such a belief?

Comment: Well, people work 9-5 jobs so they can earn money, presumably to provide for their families, or at least themselves. If Heaven is total bliss and happiness at the side of God(who presumably cares for you), then why would any need to work to earn money?

Comment: @Rajesh I wish I could ask him that!

Comment: >A< Why don't you? Isn't he your BIL step-brother?

Comment: Like I said in the question I think he isn't. His family did not raise him or his siblings religious. That's also why I phrased my question like I did--what "sort of" denomination, and what "theology" could be behind this. I thought someone on here might actually believe this, or at least know people who do.